# Confused on creating C# discord bot

Tags: c#, nuget, discord, discord.net

About a week ago I was planning on making a discord bot with C#. I do know the language decently enough to program simple things in windows forms or console apps. However, when I tried to create a discord bot using the NuGet packet manager I stumbled upon a problem: The compiler did not seem to recognize the

```
using Discord;
```

This seemed weird to me because I looked at approximately 6 different tutorials on how to make the bot. At this point I gave up because I can not debug code or whatever: I can't even start to code.

Comment: "Admins feel free to remove this post, but keep in mind that this post could really help out new coders!"  That isn't exactly how this site works.  **Self answers are encouraged here**, and posting your solution as an actual answer is the preferred way to demonstrate the solution to others.  Adding the solution to the *question body* only confuses people, which is why it tends to be stripped out.

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the answer from it and post it in the answer section.

Comment: As people have said, please [edit] your question to remove the answer from it and post your answer as an answer below to help future readers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17921514).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution to this has been found by the OP while writing the question. Turning this into a Community wiki answer per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).

All tutorials create another class. Simply don't add your Discord.NET to that, first click on your actual main class.

Comment: sorry that I didn't watch my notifications. Thanks for posting that as an answer admins!

Comment: @jellekeulemans not a problem, the answer will be better found by future readers this way. Thanks for understanding it :)